# upstart hangs on stop

Tags: django, linux, gunicorn, upstart

having an issue with upstart where i can start it but when i run

```
sudo stop up
```

it hangs

this is the .conf file

```
# my upstart django script
# this script will start/stop my django development server
# optional stuff
description "start and stop the django development server"
version "1.0"
author "Calum"

console log

# configuration variables.
# You'll want to change thse as needed
env DJANGO_HOME=/home/calum/django/django-nexus7/nexus7
env DJANGO_PORT=8000
env DJANGO_HOST=0.0.0.0 # bind to all interfaces

# tell upstart we're creating a daemon
# upstart manages PID creation for you.
expect fork

script
# My startup script, plain old shell scripting here.
chdir $DJANGO_HOME
pwd
exec /usr/bin/python manage.py run_gunicorn -c config/gunicorn
#exec /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver $DJANGO_HOST:$DJANGO_PORT &
# create a custom event in case we want to chain later
emit django_running
end script
```

would really appreciate it if someone could give me an idea of why it hangs?

Comment: yes it logs fine, and the app runs, but i just cant stop or restart it

Answer (score 4):

think i have figured it out, or atleast got something working using.

```
# my upstart django script
# this script will start/stop my django development server
# optional stuff
description "start and stop the django development server"
version "1.0"
author "Calum"

console log

# configuration variables.
# You'll want to change thse as needed
env DJANGO_HOME=/home/calum/django/django-nexus7/nexus7
env DJANGO_PORT=8000
env DJANGO_HOST=0.0.0.0 # bind to all interfaces

# tell upstart we're creating a daemon
# upstart manages PID creation for you.
#expect fork

script
# My startup script, plain old shell scripting here.
chdir $DJANGO_HOME
/usr/bin/python manage.py run_gunicorn -c config/gunicorn
end script
```

things ive learnt that may help others:

- dont use exec inside the script tags, just code it as if you were in a shell
- use expect fork if you fork once
- use expect daemon if you fork twice

Comment: Best three pieces of advice for upstart beginners